# When i am adding border/border-radius in buttons the default background changing and clicking function are not working

Tags: html, css, web, deployment

And if i remove border/border-radius from button`s css then it is working properly.
Here is my code for above question

```
<jai class="a2 az"> 
  <button onclick="men" ondblclick="mewn1">
     <img src="../images/men/1.png" alt="">
  </button>
  <div>Men`s & kids Salon,Spa & Men`s Massage</div>
</jai>

**css

 

**
#services .services2 .a .az button {
    margin-top: 33px;
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Comment: What is `<jai>` tag? Is it some framework/library?

Comment: Feels like there's more to this story.